# Parse fromPinWithName: extremely slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse iOS SDK in my app and am finding the local datastore to be abnormally slow.

In my app i'm looping through a bunch of items, for each item I run this (this is done in the background, but showing it synchronously here):

```
PFQuery *query = [DFActivity query];
[query whereKey:kDFActivityRelatedChapter equalTo:chapter];
[query fromPinWithName:kDFPinNameActivity];
[self setRelatedActivities:[query findObjects]];
```

There are only ~350-400 objects pinned with the key kDFPinNameActivity, and yet this process is taking 500ms per fetch. Given all the objects are local, and the pool of objects is relatively low, this seems like an incredibly long amount of time.

Is there something I should be doing differently to speed this process up?